# Change hover interaction to click for touch devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, touch

Need some help with hover states on a touch device.
On touch devices the hover state should be visible after one click and then a second click should fire the link.

I have modernizr with touch-events enabled, but I don`t know how to handle that in my case.

```
<div class="frontblock">
    <a href="">
        <div class="more">Here is a description</div>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/CSS.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

```css
.frontblock {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    background: #333;
    width: 50%;
}
.frontblock img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.frontblock .more {
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 130px;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}
.frontblock:hover .more {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

See it on jsfiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/rhodesign/nhDbL/

---

Let me explain my problem.

- I have multiple boxes, like a portfolio page (.frontblock).
- Every box is a link to a different page and shows an image.
- On mouseover (hover) the box is overlapped with some descriptions (.more).
- On click the link will open.

On mobile (touch devices) I want the hover (.more) to come after the first click and then a second click is necessary to fire the link.

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nhDbL/5/ or should clicked div not fade out after click? That happens because you have applied CSS ease-out transition.

Comment: On click the page will be redirected to the corresponding url. Then how will you show the effect?

Comment: @TilwinJoy He told on second click...

Comment: @j809 on first click itself we'll be redirected right..? we're clicking an actor with valid url...

Comment: No, that's what he is asking for, prevent redirect after first click and do it on second...

Comment: @Roman Did the fiddle I put up look like what you want?

Comment: no sorry j809.
I Have multiple boxes, like a portfolio page (.frontblock). Every box is a link to a different page and shows an image. On mouseover (hover) the box is overlapped with some descriptions (.more). On click the link will open.

ON MOBILE (touch devices) I will the hover (.more) to come after the first click and then a second click is necessary to fire the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

It's a raw code. Hope it's helpful

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ab = $('.frontblock a');    
    $('.frontblock a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $(".frontblock a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats not what I want. I have explained my problem little mor on top in my question.